# Can't modify a table to add a foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables

- `Songs` (SONGID, SONGNAME, ALBUM, ARRANGER, VOCALISTS, LYRCISTS)
- `Source_songs` (Source_Song_Name, ID_ACTUALSONGNAME)

and I can't modify `Songs` to add a foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE SONGS
   ADD CONSTRAINT Original_Song_Name
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (Source_song_id)                 
       REFERENCES Source_SongName (SOURCE_SONGNAME);
```

And I get this error. I know I'm spelling the column name right idk what to do.

Error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Why is my post being downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

```
Alter table Songs ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ID FOREIGN KEY(source_song_id) references ...
```

Use ADD keyword only once

Comment: ALTER TABLE SONGS

ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id

FOREIGN KEY(Source_SONG_id)

REFERENCES Source_Songs(SOURCE_SONG_ID);
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
ALTER TABLE SONGS
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id

FOREIGN KEY(Source_SONG_id)
REFERENCES Source_Songs(SOURCE_SONG_ID)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "SOURCE_SONG_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
 Tried it still doesn't work I keep getting the invalid identifier error

Comment: Is SOURCE_SONG_ID column Primary Key?

Comment: in the source_songs table yea, but even if i change that to a different column in source_songs it doesn't work I still get the same error

Comment: Edit your question and specify exact column names as you are using. Also use exact column names in Alter statement. Then it will be easy to find out your error.

Comment: alter table songs

add constraint fk_id foreign key(Source_Song_Id)

references SOURCE_SONGS(Source_Song_ID); no matter what i put in the parentheses I get this same error

Comment: @randomperson. I would reiterate Alex's comment; please past the actual DDL for both tables in your question and it should be straight forward.

Comment: What is ddl? How do I get to it?

Answer (score 0):

What is so hard to understand? The syntax is `references <table_name> ( <column_name> )`. Your table name is not `Source_SongName`, it is `Source_songs`, and it doesn't have any column named `SOURCE_SONGNAME`. You are missing the second underscore `_` in `Source_Song_Name`.

Besides, it is strange that you would have a foreign key on a column (`Source_song_id`) that doesn't exist in your table.

Or is all the information you provided made up?

Comment: alter table SONGS 

add constraint fk_bloomid 

foreign key(Source_Song_Id)

references SOURCE_SONGS(Source_Song_ID);

I changed it to this and I'm still getting the same error. For some reason oracle is not recognising any column name I put in the parentheses  after the foreign key keyword

Comment: My post was changed I think.

The tables are Songs(songid, songname, album, arranger, vocalists, lyricist)
and

Source_songs(source_song_id, title_in_english, japanese, romanji)

Comment: @randomperson - if you are sure the column names SHOULD be correct, it is possible the column names were defined in double-quotes, in which case you must use EXACTLY the same capitalization as when they were defined. (Most likely all-caps...)

Comment: I have been. I've tried every combination of cases and nothing works.

Comment: I rename the column to something else and try it doesn't work. I try other column names and it still doesn't work.